# How to get the Sheet Data in array with loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Below are my sheet data (Table)and I am trying to get the data using loop however result is not generating in the expected format

I Need data in ["11:00-12:00", "13:00-14:00"]  however it's generating in 11:00-12:0013:00-14:00

Expacted result is
var msg = ["11:00-12:00", "13:00-14:00"]

Sheet Data

[image]

```js
function showData(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var msg = ""; 

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        if(values[i][0] === "A") {

            msg += values[i][1]
        }
Logger.log(msg)

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way you are doing this, you are just making one large string. Instead of creating a string variable msg, you should make it an array and add using the .push() method.

Answer (score 1):

- `msg` should be a array and not a string
- Use [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to push items

```
function showData(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var msg = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(values[i][0] === "A") {
            msg.push(values[i][1])
        }
    }
    Logger.log(msg)
}
```